# No se pudo cargar la aplicación en el dispositivo | Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Tengo un pequeño problema con una aplicación cuando intento instalarla en un dispositivo físico (ios), puedo instalar cualquier otra aplicación en el dispositivo, pero esa específica me saca ese error y aparece una leyenda que dice "no se pudo cargar la aplicación en el dispositivo "

¿Alguna idea de por qué sucede eso?

-PD. Ya había instalado la aplicación en ese dispositivo hace varios días, pero ese error acaba de suceder.

Esto solo sucede con un dispositivo físico iOS, con emuladores funcionan perfectamente y con dispositivos Android también funciona.

Esta es la salida que me da:

```
Installing application bundle 'com.onavarro.AppJoynder' on 'iPhone de Jovany Elizalde'

Installing application bundle 'com.onavarro.AppJoynder' on 'iPhone de Jovany Elizalde'
 TransferringPackage - PercentComplete: 10%

 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 10%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 11%
 .....................
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 98%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 98%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 98%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CreatingStagingDirectory - PercentComplete: 5%
 ExtractingPackage - PercentComplete: 15%
 InspectingPackage - PercentComplete: 20%
 TakingInstallLock - PercentComplete: 20%
 PreflightingApplication - PercentComplete: 30%
 InstallingEmbeddedProfile - PercentComplete: 30%
 VerifyingApplication - PercentComplete: 40%
 ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.O19Qy5/extracted/AppJoynder.iOS.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/Jovany/Documents/JOYNDER APP/oscarnavarroc10/joynder.git/AppJoynder.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone6.1-11.3.1/AppJoynder.iOS.app' on the device 'iPhone de Jovany Elizalde': Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016).

No se pudo cargar la aplicación en el dispositivo.
```

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que menciona @fredyfx acerca de los Entitlements podría ser, pero apostaría más a que el Provisioning Profile que estás usando no tiene configurado el dispositivo en el que está desplegando la aplicación, ya que mencionaste que en el simulador sí te funcionó.

La forma más sencilla de configurarlo sería usando la herramienta de Automatic Provisioning dentro de tu archivo `Info.plist`.

[image: Automatic Provisiong]

Conectas tu dispositivo, seleccionas la opción mencionada, colocas tu cuenta de desarrollador y Visual Studio se encargará de agregar el dispositivo a tu Provisioning Profile automáticamente.

Si prefieres la forma manual, puedes seguir un tutorial como este:  https://smallbusiness.chron.com/provision-iphone-development-36933.html

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué tipo de Entitlements utiliza tu app? Sucede que tu error:

```
ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.O19Qy5/extracted/AppJoynder.iOS.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/Jovany/Documents/JOYNDER APP/oscarnavarroc10/joynder.git/AppJoynder.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone6.1-11.3.1/AppJoynder.iOS.app' on the device 'iPhone de Jovany Elizalde': Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016).
```

Se resume en:

```
(The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. 
Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile,     
or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile.
Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016).
```

Y esto es normalmente una falta de coincidencia entre lo que tu App requiere y lo que el perfil de provisionamiento permite.

Por ejemplo, tu app requiere App Groups u otro Entitlement y no le das estos permisos.

Revisa a detalle el siguiente enlace para mayores detalles:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_property_lists/#Entitlements.plist

Answer (score 0):

Dices que lo probaste en este dispositivo días antes, pero igual es bueno checar en la página de [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com) que este registrado/agregado (> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Devices ) y que en el Provisioning Profiles   (> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles >Provisioning Profiles) vaya incluido el dispositivo y no este caducado.

Y ya que verifiques que todo este correcto, descargarlo por medio de xcode y creo que es todo, es lo que recuerdo de esos pasos.